# How to make unrecognized faces in opencv2 be labeled "unknown"?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, webcam, image-recognition

I am trying to run some python 2.7 code with opencv2. Currently if a subject enters the frame the code labels them as the one it looks like most in its photo database. Instead of this I would like it to label untrained faces as "unknown" this is my code so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);
rec=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
rec.load("recognizer\\trainingData.yml")
id=0
font=cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,1,0,0)
#font=cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,3,1,0,1)
while (True):
   ret, img=cam.read();
   gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);
   for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        #cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
        id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])
        if(id==1):
            id="Admin"
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
        elif(id==2):
            id="Sonja"
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),2)
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),2)
        cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img),str(id),(x,y+h),font,(255,255,255));
    cv2.imshow("Image",img);
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the trainer is run through this code:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
path='dataSet'

def getImagesWithID(path):
   imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
   faces=[]
   IDs=[]
   for imagePath in imagePaths:
        faceImg=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L');
        faceNp=np.array(faceImg,'uint8')
        ID=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
        faces.append(faceNp)
        print ID
        IDs.append(ID)
        cv2.imshow("training",faceNp)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
    return np.array(IDs), faces

Ids, faces= getImagesWithID(path)
recognizer.train(faces, Ids)
recognizer.save('recognizer/trainingData.yml')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your rec.predict method returns the id of the recognized faces. In which case you can add an 'else' condition in the `for (x,y,w,h) in faces:` loop for the faces that don't have an id, like so:

```
        if(id==1):
            id="Admin"
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
            cv2.putText(img,"Admin",x+h/2,y+w+40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.6,(0,255,255),2)
        elif(id==2):
            id="Sonja"
            #cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),2)
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),2)
            cv2.putText(img,"Sonja",x+h/2,y+w+40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.6,(255,255,255),2)
        else:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)#Red
            cv2.putText(img,"Unknown",(x+h/2,y+w+40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.6,(0,0,255),2)
```

Also, I've implemented the putText method differently than the one you've shown.

Comment: Thanks @Saransh Kejriwai however I had tried this to, with no luck.

Comment: It could be an issue with the way you've implemented PutText(). I've updated my answer

Comment: I'm really sorry Saransh to inconvenience but the updated answer doesn't work either. Do you have any other  ideas?

Comment: What is the output that you get ?

Comment: Sonja or Admin.

Comment: So with my implementation of putText, you can see Sonja or Admin. Do you see the red rectangle surrounding the unknown face. If not, then it means that the else condition is never executed, thereby implying that you need to check the id field

Comment: I do not have the red box appear it changes between yellow (admin) and white(sonja). How would I go about checking the id field?

Comment: You''ll need to check your training data...it's likely that 1 of the 2 faces is being recognised under any given condition

Answer (score 0):

If you print the value of *conf* you can see that the value will be less than *70* if the face is in the dataset you made otherwise the value of *conf* will be more than *70*. The value *70* is set by me if you want the system be more accurate check the value of *conf* and give any other value as your wish.

Comment: I would suggest adding a simple code snippet to backup your answer.

Comment: Thank you Anuraj S, I'm still getting this issue and in fact it now can misrecognise me as "Sonja" I have added above the trainer perhaps I'm over looking something there could you please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import sleep


faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rec=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
rec.load("recognizer/trainingData.yml")
id=0
font=cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1,1,0,1)
while True:
    ret,img=cam.read();
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])
        if(conf<70):
            if(id==1):
                id="Admin"
            if(id==2):
                id="Sonja"
        else:
            id="unknown"

        cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img), str(id), (x,y+h), font,255)
        print ('ok')
    cv2.imshow("Face",img)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q')):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you Anuraj S, I'm still getting this issue and in fact it now can misrecognise me as "Sonja" I have added above the trainer perhaps I'm over looking something there could you please take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
if conf<70:
        if id !=0 & id !=1:
            cv2.putText(img,"unknown",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```